# How to load Keras Model in Django rest API views

Tags: django, keras, django-rest-framework

*api_views.py* 
`from keras.models import load_model`

```
model = load_model('saved_finger_print_model.h5')
```

**And I got this error!**

```
OSError: Unable to open file (unable to open file: name = 'saved_finger_print_model.h5', errno = 2, error message = 'No such file or directory', flags = 0, o_flags = 0)
```

Comment: NOTE: saved_finger_print_model.h5 is in the same folder with the api_views.py file

Comment: Where is `saved_finger_print_model.h5` saved? Looks like a path issue to me.

Comment: You can try getting file path using `os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'app_name', 'h5file')`

Answer (score 0):

okay, guys, I was able to solve this challenge by placing  the `saved_finger_print_model.h5` file in my project directory, (the same directory where I have my `manage.py`) file and when I placed the code  
  `model = load_model('saved_finger_print_model.h5')` 
 in my `api_views.py` file which was in my app directory (the same directory where I have models.py views.py, etc.), it worked very fine.